# Punctuating a two part question

Tags: semicolons, question-mark

I'm trying to figure out how to best punctuate this.  I'm torn between ; or ?

> Have we looked at this paper? Do we intend to?
>
> Have we looked at this paper; do we intend to?

I want to say the first is correct, but it feels awkward seeing "do we intend to" as a full sentence, because its not.

Comment: I prefer the two, independent, consecutive questions. Yes, "Do we intend to?", on its own, feels incomplete. But the two questions together do form a complete thought.  It is like pulling "He shined it." out of context. Some male shined something -- very useful.  But consider: *Tom found a ring. He shined it.* The two sentences now fit together to form the complete thought.

Comment: Consider the second sentence in your question: "I'm torn between ; or ?". Just like "Do we intend to?", it lacks context when read on its own. In conjunction with its preceding sentence, though, it makes sense.

Comment: You could add "If not, do we intend to?" if you find just the last four words awkward on their own. Personally I agree with the comments above that "Do we intend to?" by itself is fine in context.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your first example works fine. In a manuscript, you might use a carriage break if you think it looks funny

*Have we looked at this paper?*

*Do we intend to?*

To stack the questionss, I don't prefer the semicolon; although I think it's OK. But I would use a conjunction with a comma.

*Have we looked at this paper, and do we intend to?*

Still this gives the feeling of an indirect question followed by a direct question. If your intent is two direct questions, I would use your first example.